# Why can't Terraform list SQL users in GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

Following examples laid out here - https://medium.com/@mudrii/google-gke-and-sql-with-terraform-294fb840619d

I have a basic Terraform file that creates a DB and a user:

```
resource "random_id" "id" {
  byte_length = 4
  prefix      = "${local.resource_prefix}-"
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
  name             = random_id.id.hex
  region           = local.gcp_region
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"

  settings {
    availability_type = "ZONAL"
    tier              = "db-f1-micro"
    disk_type         = "PD_SSD"
    disk_size         = 10
    disk_autoresize   = true

    ip_configuration {
      authorized_networks {
        value = "0.0.0.0/0"
      }

      require_ssl  = false
      ipv4_enabled = true
    }

    location_preference {
      zone = local.subnet_public_1_az
    }

    backup_configuration {
      #      binary_log_enabled = true
      enabled            = true
      start_time         = "00:00"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_user" "user" {
  depends_on = [
    google_sql_database_instance.postgres
  ]

  instance = google_sql_database_instance.postgres.name
  name     = "*********"
  password = "*********"
}
```

That seems to create the database with no problem, but when it goes to create a user for that DB it fails with a 403:

```
google_sql_database_instance.postgres: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]

Error: Error, attempting to list users associated with instance foo-aac6b6f7: googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized

  on postgres.tf line 6, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres":
   6: resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
```

Turning on verbose logging, the underlying error would appear to be the following:

```
GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-id)/instances/foo-aac6b6f7/users?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1

{
   "error": {
     "code": 403,
     "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request.",
     "errors": [
       {
         "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request.",
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "notAuthorized"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why I would get a permission denied here, or how to get it that permission.  I tried the request from the command line using the same credential file and it seemed to work fine:

```
gcloud sql users list --instance foo-aac6b6f7 --credential-file-override ~/gcp.json
NAME      HOST
*********
```

What's the special sauce?  Is the service account I'm using with Terraform not allowed to make the request?  Then why would it work from the command line?  Is it just trying to add the users too soon after the DB is created?  If so how should this work?

---

*EDIT* I removed everything other than the `google_sql_database_instance`, created a new service account and made sure it had project owner role.

I then followed the log with trace debugging on.  It begins by successfully requesting a DB creation, and then begins to poll the request waiting for it to finish:

```
2020/06/11 18:28:50 [DEBUG] Waiting for state to become: [success]
...
GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-id)/operations/(request-id)?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
 {
  "kind": "sql#operation",
  "targetLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-name)/instances/(db-name)",
  "status": "RUNNING",
  "user": "(service-account)@(project-name).iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "insertTime": "2020-06-11T22:26:46.845Z",
  "startTime": "2020-06-11T22:26:47.141Z",
  "operationType": "CREATE",
  "name": "(request-id)",
  "targetId": "(db-name)",
  "selfLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-name)/operations/(request-id)",
  "targetProject": "(project-name)"
 }
```

It does that for a while until it gets a `DONE` state:

```
2020/06/11 18:30:43 [DEBUG] Got DONE while polling for operation (request-id)'s status
```

It then proceeds to look up the database, but that operation fails:

```
GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-id)/instances/(db-name)?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1
...
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
...
 {
   "error": {
     "code": 404,
     "message": "The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.",
     "errors": [
       {
         "message": "The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.",
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "instanceDoesNotExist"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

So that's really the root error.  It doesn't seem to actually fail on that request though, eventually reporting:

```
2020/06/11 18:30:44 [WARN] Removing SQL Database Instance "(db-name)" because it's gone
```

But it doesn't actually remove the DB (it's still there in the console), and Terraform keeps going, requesting users from the DB now:

```
GET /sql/v1beta4/projects/(project-id)/instances/(db-name)/users?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1
...
 {
   "error": {
     "code": 403,
     "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request.",
     "errors": [
       {
         "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request.",
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "notAuthorized"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

*THIS* is the error that's actually reported, but a whole mess happened before that actual error.  So... Anyone know what's going on here?  Why does the DB creation succeed, and then the lookup immediately fail?  And why does Terraform keep going?

Comment: Note - I seem to get the same problem if I omit the `google_sql_user` resource altogether.  So it seems to be purely in creating the `google_sql_database_instance` resource.

Comment: Created a new service account, made sure it had `project owner` and `Cloud SQL admin` roles.  swapped out the config files - same result...

Comment: Notice that for Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instances the [default user account must be configured in order to be able to connect to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-users#user-root). I think that the permissions error you are receiving has to do with this and not exactly about the permissions of the service account itself.

Comment: Please test by modifying the .tf file in the following way: 1. [Create a database resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database.html#example-usage-sql-database-basic) prior to creating the users. 2. Create the default user account for the Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance by setting the `name` attribute of the `google_sql_user` resource to `"postgres"` and afterwards adding a new `google_sql_user` resource with the specific new user that you want to create.